# Solr doc value for fields in schema browsers is way off

Tags: solr, solrcloud

- The doc value in solr admin [1] for field keywords is 33563
- When searching via "q=keywords:[* TO *]" the response states numFound: 50314

Is this a known bug or is the count in the admin cached? Is there a way to update the value for the schema browser?

Used is SolrCloud 4.10, the problem also exists in SolrCloud with version 5.5.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Browser+Screen

Comment: Possibly this reflects that you have deleted some documents without "optimizing"?  This leaves documents in the collection, but marked as ready for deletion.  I know that in the "doc count" these kind of discrepancies show up and are cleared away if the collection is "optimized" (which deletes the old, unwanted docs.)  You might try optimizing and then re-checking the counts.

Comment: Are you sure that the field is loaded from across the collection and not from the local instance only?